# What is a good library in Python for correlated fits in both the $x$ and $y$ data?

Tags: python, least-squares, curve-fitting

I have $x$ and $y$ data, both of which have their own covariance matrices.  `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` will accept a covariance matrix for the $y$ data, called `sigma`, but not for $x$ data.  I would like to pass a covariance matrix for my $x$ data also since it is also correlated.

I found `scipy.odr`, however, the 2d-array option for `we` and `wd`, as well as for `covx` and `covy` do not work (I have submitted an issue on github).

I have written my own ODR code in python, however, it's quite slow.  The ODRPACK that `scipy.odr` uses I imagine is quite fast since it is FORTRAN.

I thought I would probe to see if people knew of a nice option, in place of me using the slow code I wrote.

**Is there an alternative to `scipy.odr` for fitting correlated $x$ and $y$ data using python?**

Answer (score 3):

Here is the current code I am using to do correlated fits in the $x$ and $y$ directions.  I wrote it from [this reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odrpack_guide.pdf).  I adapted it from section **1.A.i** and **4.B**

```
#!/anaconda/bin/python

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares



class Fitter(object):
    """
    Orthogonal distance regression (ODR) fitter object.
    """

    def __init__(self,):
        pass

    def Model(self, function):
        """
        Set the model to fit to.
        """
        self.model = function

    def Beta0(self, init_beta):
        """
        Set the initial parameters.
        """
        self.beta0 = np.array(init_beta)
        self.bs = len(init_beta)

    def Data(self, xdata, ydata, sigmax=None, sigmay=None, covx=None, covy=None):
        """
        Input the x and y data, as well as the errors if they exist.
        """
        if (len(xdata) != len(ydata)):
            raise ValueError("x and y data must have same shape")
        self.x = xdata
        self.y = ydata
        self.xs = len(xdata)
        self.ys = len(ydata)
        self.delta = np.zeros(shape=(self.xs,))
        if (sigmax is not None) and (sigmay is not None):
            Omega = np.block([[np.diag(1./sigmay**2), np.zeros((self.ys, self.ys))],
                              [np.zeros((self.xs, self.xs)), np.diag(1./sigmax**2)]])
        elif (sigmax is not None) and (sigmay is None):
            Omega = np.block([[np.eye(self.xs), np.zeros((self.ys, self.ys))],
                              [np.zeros((self.xs, self.xs)), np.diag(1./sigmax**2)]])
        elif (sigmax is None) and (sigmay is not None):
            Omega = np.block([[np.diag(1./sigmay**2), np.zeros((self.ys, self.ys))],
                              [np.zeros((self.xs, self.xs)), np.eye(self.xs)]])
        elif (covx is not None) and (covy is not None):
            Omega = np.block([[np.linalg.inv(covy), np.zeros((self.ys, self.ys))],
                              [np.zeros((self.xs, self.xs)), np.linalg.inv(covx)]])
        elif (covx is None) and (covy is not None):
            Omega = np.block([[np.linalg.inv(covy), np.zeros((self.ys, self.ys))],
                              [np.zeros((self.xs, self.xs)), np.eye(self.xs)]])
        elif (covx is not None) and (covy is None):
            Omega = np.block([[np.eye(self.xs), np.zeros((self.ys, self.ys))],
                              [np.zeros((self.xs, self.xs)), np.linalg.inv(covx)]])
        else:
            Omega = np.eye(2*self.xs)

        self.L = np.linalg.cholesky(Omega)
        assert np.allclose(Omega, self.L.dot(self.L.transpose()))


    def Residuals(self, z):
        """
        Calculates the sum of residuals for ODR.
        """
        para = z[:self.bs]
        arguments = z[self.bs:]

        rx = arguments
        ry = (self.model(self.x + rx, *para) - self.y)
        r = np.hstack((ry, rx))

        return np.dot(r, self.L)

    def Run(self,):
        """
        Runs the fitter.
        """
        self.whole = np.append(self.beta0, self.delta)
        self.out = least_squares(self.Residuals, self.whole, method='lm')
        self.chi2 = np.sum(self.out.fun**2) / float(len(self.x)-len(self.beta0))
```

One passes in a function as the fitting form to `Model`, sets the initial guess with `Beta0`, passes in the data and errors (or covariances) with `Data`, then runs to find the best fit parameters with `Run`.

Mathematically what I think ODR does, and what I wrote here is trying to minimize weighted least squares.  If $C^{(x)}$ and $C^{(y)}$ are covariance matrices for $x$ and $y$ data (or their diagonals for the squared errors) we try to minimize the expression,
$$
\sum_{i,j} (f(\bar{x}_i, \beta_{k}) - y_i) {C^{(y)}}^{-1}_{ij} (f(\bar{x}_j, \beta_{k}) - y_j) +  (\bar{x}_{i} - x_{i}) {C^{(x)}}^{-1}_{ij} (\bar{x}_{j} - x_{j}) 
$$
where $\beta_{k}$ are the fit parameters, $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$ are the the data, $f$ is some fit function, and $\bar{x}_{i}$ is some ideal $x$ value that minimizes this expression.  So in some sense one is solving for $\beta$ and $\bar{x}$.  Alternatively we can replace $\delta_{i} \equiv (\bar{x}_{i} - x_{i})$, which gives $\bar{x}_{i} = \delta_{i} + x_{i}$, giving a new expression,
$$
\sum_{i,j} (f(\delta_{i} + x_{i}, \beta_{k}) - y_i) {C^{(y)}}^{-1}_{ij} (f(\delta_j + x_j, \beta_{k}) - y_j) +  \delta_i {C^{(x)}}^{-1}_{ij} \delta_j
$$
Putting the $x$ and $y$ inverse covariances in a block-diagonal matrix and taking Cholesky decomposition (the covariance matrices have to be Hermitian at least), This is dotted with the $x$ and $y$ residuals.  This final vector when squared and summed (or dotted with itself) gives the sum of the squares which is what the `scipy.least_squares` wants.

Comment: Could you please add fake data to test your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a option:
**lsqfit** : https://pypi.org/project/lsqfit/

With documentation here: https://lsqfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Developed for and works very well for Lattice QCD. But useful more generally.

Very simple and easy to use.

Internally uses **gvar** (https://pypi.org/project/gvar/ , for storing correlations.